# How to set magnet links to open in a CLI program?

Tags: command-line, bash, firefox, torrent-client

(Running Kubuntu 19.10, Firefox 73.0.1, KDE Plasma 5.18.2)

Hi all,

I have recently discovered a CLI-program called peerflix that allows the user to stream torrents. For example the command: `peerflix "[magnet link]" --vlc` would open a magnet link for streaming in VLC.

Would there be any way to get this to automatically run when I click a magnet link in Firefox like how you could for a torrent client?

(i.e. getting it to run from this dialog)

[image: the Launch image dialog]

Thanks for any and all assistance!

EDIT: I installed peerflix with the command `npm install -g peerflix`. The source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix)

Comment: If `peerflix` isn't in the standard repos, please [edit] your question to provide a link to its source and explain how you installed it.

Comment: Here's something from 2014: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/peerflix-stream-torrents-with-vlc-or.html

Comment: @DKBose thank you so much the solution you posted worked perfectly! I will add it as an answer now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As per the [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/03/peerflix-stream-torrents-with-vlc-or.html) DK Bose posted, I was able to get this working!**

1. Firstly, install vlc, xterm, python-libtorrent and wget:

   `sudo apt-get install vlc xterm python-libtorrent wget`
2. To be able to open torrent files from Firefox and play them with VLC via Peerflix:

   `wget https://raw.github.com/hotice/webupd8/master/Torrent-Video-Player -O /tmp/Torrent-Video-Player`

   `sudo install /tmp/Torrent-Video-Player /usr/local/bin/`

   Then when you open your browser and click a torrent, select other and browse for  */usr/local/bin/Torrent-Video-Player*
3. To get magnet links to work:

   `wget https://raw.github.com/danfolkes/Magnet2Torrent/master/Magnet_To_Torrent2.py -O /tmp/Magnet_To_Torrent2.py`

   `sudo install /tmp/Magnet_To_Torrent2.py /usr/local/bin/`

   `wget https://raw.github.com/hotice/webupd8/master/Magnet-Video-Player -O /tmp/Magnet-Video-Player`

   `sudo install /tmp/Magnet-Video-Player /usr/local/bin/`

   Then when you open your browser and click a magnet link, select other and browse for  */usr/local/bin/Magnet-Video-Player*